# Inserting xml response(SOAP response) in sqlserver Column of data type of type "xml" from java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, prepared-statement, persistence

I have a SOAP response which needs to be persisted in the data base as it is(no-parsing). I have the whole response as string and need to persist it. I'm doing it as. The requestXML and responseXML are strings

```
String sql ="INSERT INTO TABLE(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, value1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2,value2);
            preparedStatement.setString(3,value3);
            preparedStatement.setDate(4, value4);
            preparedStatement.setString(5,requestXML);
            preparedStatement.setString(6,responseXML);
            preparedStatement.setString(7,value7 );
            preparedStatement.setString(8,value8);
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(9,value9);
            preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The above code has exception "**String or binary data would be truncated**"

the DB column for both requestXML and responseXML  are of dataType "XML" and length set to "-1"

The xml in the table should be like a hyperlink meaning, it should be clickable. Onclick it shows the xml

Comment: When you say "no-parsing" are you ruling out the use of `preparedStatement.setSQLXML` as described in the Java tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlxml.html)?

Comment: Yes. The xml in the table must me like a hyperlink

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "like a hyperlink" and why you cannot use the actual XML features of JDBC when working with your XML data.